# object X is not a member of package Y

Tags: java, scala, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to implement an abstract Java class in Scala and in the eclipse IDE it is not showing errors but, when I try to compile it is throwing an error

**The abstract Java class is defined as**

```
package de.hybris.platform.webservices;

import de.hybris.platform.core.model.ItemModel;


public abstract class AbstractCommand<RESOURCE> extends AbstractYResponseBuilder<RESOURCE, Object, Object> implements
        Command<RESOURCE, Object, Object>
{
    ...
}
```

**Code for Scala class is**

```
package com.test.scala.poc.ws

import de.hybris.platform.webservices.AbstractCommand
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel

class ProductCommand extends AbstractCommand[ProductModel] {

  override def execute(resourceModel: ProductModel, requestDTO: Object): ProductModel = null


}
```

**And finally, the damn error message is**

```
object webservices is not a member of package de.hybris.platform
```

Help resolving this is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to clean the involved projects?

Answer (score 3):

It happens due to saved build logs of a previously failed build. Clean the build, close and restart IDE. It should be all fine.

Comment: yes. It dute to previously failed build. I works in IntelliJ IDEA and this procedure worked for me. (1) File -> Invalidated Caches / Restart ... -> Just Restart. (2) Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ's `Invalidated Caches and Restart` was not enough in my case, but after discarding the folders `.bloop/` and `target/` and reimporting the `bsp` project in Intellij (`build.sbt` then was consumed again and has gone to bloop) things were fine.